# Global variable doesn't get updated

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a Chuck Norris joke generator.
I have a generate new joke button that fetches a new joke from the api and i have a few buttons with different joke categories.

I have a global variable  called `categories` which i am trying to mutate whenever a category button is clicked but the variable continues having the default value when a new joke is fetched.

What am i doing wrong ?

here is the code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', start);
let category = 'animal';

async function fetchJoke(arrayz) {
    const response = await Promise.all(arrayz.map(url => fetch(url).then(response => response.json())));

    return response;
}

function start() {
    console.log('ready');
    fetchJoke(arrayz).then(render);
}

const arrayz = [`https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category=${category}`, 'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/categories'];


function render(data) {
    const main = document.querySelector('main');
    main.innerHTML = '';
    const clone = document.querySelector('.template').content.cloneNode(true);
    const joke = clone.querySelector('p');

    joke.textContent = data[0].value;

    clone.querySelector('.zbutton').addEventListener('click', () => {
        start();
    });
    createButton(data, clone);

    main.appendChild(clone);
}

function createButton(data, clone) {
    data[1].map(category => {
        const button = document.createElement('button');
        button.appendChild(document.createTextNode(category));
        button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            category = e.target.innerText;
            start();
        });

        clone.querySelector('.buttons').appendChild(button);
    })
}
```

link to jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/rcej8mkf/4/

Comment: The `${category}` in const arrays will only get evaluated once on page load and never after the `category` value changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two variables named `category`.

- One created with `let` at the top of the script, which you only ever read from.
- One which is the name of the first and only argument passed to the function you pass to `map` near the end.

You overwrite the latter, but then never read from it again.

---

If you want to overwrite the global one at the point, don't mask it with another variable of the same name in a narrower scope.

Of course that brings up another issue, which is that you only ever *read* from the global `category` variable **once**, when you generate the string to assign to the first item in `arrayz`.

You'll need to update it inside `start` for it to do any good.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot, its working perfectly now!

Answer (score 1):

`arrayz` is only computed once, with the initial value of `category`. `arrayz` is never updated. Try putting the `arrayz` definition inside your `start` function.

EDIT: and the category global is being shadowed by the argument, as others mentioned.